# Pass JButton to Utility class. Acceptable?

Tags: java, swing, static, jframe, jbutton

I have a JFrame that does things. I have a JButton hidden from view in that JFrame. In a SwingWorker i have a utility Class such as checkNDownloadFile of which I pass a JButton to it. So it can make it visible/usable when the process completes.

My question is, is this acceptable. I dont know of any other method to do this effect. (Keep in mind the checkNDownloadFile class is all static. Its only needed/ran once.)

---

### Sudo Code

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
myWorker Class

protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

    //Loading time consuming data.
    //Execute Dialog of the question variety.
    //Loading more time consuming data.

    //Create JFrame
    AtomFrame frame = new AtomFrame();
    frame.start();

    checkNDownloadFile.setButton(frame.fileButton)
    checkNDownloadFile.start();
    return null;
}

-----------------------------------------------------------------
checkNDownloadFile Class

public static void start() {
    //Do the other task at hand
    if (complete && good) {
        fileButton.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        //other stuff
    }
}
```

---

### Answer Code

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
myWorker Class

protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

    //Loading time consuming data.
    //Execute Dialog of the question variety.
    //Loading more time consuming data.

    //Create JFrame
    //Moved to Main Method to be created by EDT.
    //AtomFrame frame = new AtomFrame();
    //frame.start();

    publish("Executing");
    boolean returnedB = checkNDownloadFile.start();
    if (returnedB) {
        publish("Good");
    } else {
        //Maybe implement
        //checkNDownloadFile.getError();
        publish("Bad");
    }
    return null;
}

-----------------------------------------------------------------
checkNDownloadFile Class

public static void start() {
    //Do the other task at hand
    if (complete && good) {
        return true
    } else {
        //Maybe implement
        //setError("");
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Do not* update the GUI from your implementation of `doInBackground()`.
2. *Do* update the GUI from your implementation of `process()` or `done()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513), and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).
3. You may have to re-factor your `checkNDownloadFile()` method to provide the desired granularity for a sensible progress display.
4. See also [*Watching a Directory for Changes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

Comment: If i were to put the checkNDownloadFile.start() into done() wouldn't that defeat the point?

Comment: Correct; you should `publish()` intermediate results concering the download from `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Ah, right on. So is it still ok to create the JFrame in this SwingWorker as well? just as long as I update it using done/publish or another swingworker later.

Comment: the checkNDownloadFile will not have a progress with it. Just four states, Off-Executing-Good-Bad

Comment: No; create the frame on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); see also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20603012/230513).