# Updating buttons inside or outside of SwingWorker?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I want to disable a number of buttons/menu items of my GUI while a SwingWorker thread is running. The thread is started when a button is clicked.

It looks like the while loop in my code causes the CPU load to go up significantly. Did I get something wrong about how to determine if a SwingWorker thread is still running?

The CPU load's definitely lower when I update the buttons/menu items inside the SwingWorker thread. However, I felt like that shouldn't be the SwingWorker thread's job. Should it?

```
JButton button = new JButton("Start");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        menu.setEnabled(false);

        MySwingWorker worker = new MySwingWorker();
        worker.execute();

        while (true) {
          if (worker.isCancelled() || worker.isDone()) {
            menu.setEnabled(true);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    });
    t.start();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) (EDT). Doing so from `t` is incorrect. As suggested in examples cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23029042/230513), condition your GIU elements on the EDT *before* starting the [worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), and update the GUI in `process()` or `done()`.

Comment: One more question: Would it be allowed to dynamically create a JOptionPane from the button's ActionListener ("Congratulations, you clicked a button")? Having a worker for that seems a bit oversized for that purpose.

Comment: Unless you intentionally do otherwise, the button's listener will be invoked on the EDT. Note, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18728637/230513), that the EDT will continue to process events posted from `process()`, even if a modal dialog blocks user interaction with other windows.