# Unresponsive swing worker

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I am having a hard time to use the Swing worker to work with my project. It has two programs, one is the [logic (full program)](http://pastebin.com/VHqBuENM) and the other is GUI. I am calling the logic program from the GUI. And because of its unresponsiveness, I tried using Swing worker. But even if I use Swing worker, its still unresponsive. If I run the program, it displays the GUI, but if I click on start, the another program starts and it becomes unresponsive.

This the snippet of [GUI program](http://pastebin.com/nN3jhLTz) (full program):

```
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            state.setText("Listening");
            System.out.println("Started Listening");
            state.setBackground(new Color(51, 204, 0));
            doRun(args);
        }
    });

public void doRun(String[] args) {

    SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>(){

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // Object to use from another program 
            HelloWorld obj = new HelloWorld();
            obj.main(args);
            return null;
        }};
        worker.execute();
}
```

Comment: Did you try either of [these suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28977281/230513) in this possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28971487/230513)?

Comment: @trashgod Yes, that is what I was trying. As you said and others said to use the swing worker. But I am not able to make it a responsive GUI, or to run the sphinx program in the background.

Comment: Instead of running `HelloWorld#main()` , instantiate a `LiveSpeechRecognizer` and `publish()` the results.

Comment: @trashgod How will I pass the `args` to look up for the configuration? Could you please kindly help me with the code in the answer, I am having a hard time grasping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it requires interaction, it may be inconvenient to run `HelloWorld#main()` in the background. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28977281/230513), instantiate a [`LiveSpeechRecognizer`](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/doc/sphinx4/edu/cmu/sphinx/api/LiveSpeechRecognizer.html) directly in your [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and `publish()` interim results for display in the GUI. You can specify `Configuration` information in the `SwingWorker` constructor or pass it as a parameter. In outline based on examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20603012/230513) and [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4),

```
private class BackgroundTask extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer;

    public BackgroundTask() {
        statusLabel.setText((this.getState()).toString());
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
        configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.dmp");
        recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
        recognizer.startRecognition(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() {
        while (!isCancelled()) {
            SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
            List<WordResult> list = result. getWords();
            for (WordResult w : list) {
                // get information to publish, e.g. getPronunciation()
                // publish(getSpelling());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(java.util.List<String> messages) {
        statusLabel.setText((this.getState()).toString());
        for (String message : messages) {
            textArea.append(message + "\n");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        recognizer.stopRecognition();
        statusLabel.setText((this.getState()).toString() + " " + status);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        bar.setIndeterminate(false);
    }

}
```