# MusicXML files in java swing - visual representation and dynamic editing

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, musicxml

I'm developing a desktop application with java swing which should be able to display the visual content (notes, clefs, measures) defined in a MusicXML file in the frame. All .xml parsers that I found allow me to only create trees. I couldn't display the content with the JEditorPane, too.

Can I do it or will I need to first transform it dynamically to some other format such as .pdf? If so - how can I do it in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `JTextArea` to let the user edit raw XML. Load the file in the background using [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20603012/230513), to mitigate the effect of any latency.

[image]

```
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground() {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("build.xml"));
        String s;
        try {
            while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                publish(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

> By visual representation, I meant that I needed a way to display [this type of visual output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MusicXML_C_Whole_Note.png).

You might look at the [`JMusicXML`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmusicxml/) project, which has "some Java `awt/swing` graphics player." More resources may be found [here](http://www.musicxml.com/software/).

[image]