# Java: How will I be able to create a Stop JButton which will stop the Runnable() thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have created a simple HTTP server in Java by using a ServerSocket that accepts browser requests. The server is working fine without any errors. I have created a JForm using Swing that contains buttons to start and stop the server. In the start button I have added an ActionListener that runs my ServerMain class.

```
btnStartServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    try {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { 
                ServerMain.main(new String[0]);
            }
         }).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}});
```

How will I be able to create a Stop JButton which will stop the Runnable() thread?

Comment: Can you share ServerMain.main() code?

Comment: There's no guaranteed way of stopping a `Thread` other then to program the code in thread to support it. Your server should be monitoring the interrupted state of the current thread and you should have a flag (probably an `AtomicBoolean`) that you can change and check the state of to determine of the thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the server in the context of a class that implements the [`cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) method of [`Future<V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). [`SwingWorker<T,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) is such a [`RunnableFuture<V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RunnableFuture.html); a complete example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20603012/230513).

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to just kill a thread (by using `Thread.stop()`). The reasons why are listed in [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

I assume the code in `ServerMain.main(String... args)` runs some kind of `while(condition)` loop, like this:

```
public class ServerMain{
    public static boolean condition = true;

    public static void main(String... args){
        while(condition){
            //do stuff
        }
        //close sockets and other streams.
        //Call Thread.interupt() on all sleeping threads
    }
}
```

Your button should set this condition to false somehow:

```
stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        try {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    // set condition to false;
                    ServerMain.condition = false;
                }
            }.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```