# how to update Progressbar when runnable jar is run?

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, splash-screen

I have a project for splash screen with progress bar and I have a separate runnable jar file. I want to run jar and update the progress bar in my project. To do that I'm using exec() method.
What would be the approach to update progressbar?

Comment: You need to show some code.  There's so very many ways of displaying a progress bar... what have you tried?

Comment: @markspace I haven't tried yet. I have just got stuck in very idea that 'what would be ideal approach to this problem'. I can think of two solutions to this problem. 1) Based on jar file size and time of execution of jar file 2) Based on progressing in windows form(jar).

Comment: See also (the official) [`SplashScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html).

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20603012/230513).

Comment: @trashgod. ya something similar but i don't want to make use of setIndeterminate() method. rather i want to update progress bar by setValue() method in range of (0-100).

Comment: @trashgod will it be a good approach if I introduce special ID with every single window in my application(jar) which will be read using inputStream, and based on ID assigned progress bar will be updated?

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25526869/230513) shows "changes to display intermediate progress."