# Java wait for a process to finish and upload modified file into database

Tags: java, swing, oracleforms

I'am looking for a way to open a MS Word application with Java and after user finish to edit opened document with MS Word the process must upload modified file into database.

I have tryed to use Process command and waitFor method but Java is not waiting for the process to finish..

Any other solution? or idea how to do this?
example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int exitValue = 0;
            //open MS WORD....
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler winword "+filename);
            //wait for a process to finish..
            int i = p.waitFor();
            //upload modified file to database
            upload(...);
            System.out.println(i);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Swing requires that your program construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). When the user concludes editing, execute a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) that handles the upload in your implementation of `doInBackground()` using `ProcessBuilder`. Optionally, display diagnostic output from the upload process in a `JTextArea`.  Invoke `setProgress()` as desired; a listening `JProgressBar` will update itself accordingly. Mark the file as saved in your implementation of `done()`.

A related example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20603012/230513).

[image]