# How to implement Eclipse's 'Terminate' button functaionality in Swings application

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, selenium

Suppose we have a Java Swings application, which has been used to run Selenium WebDriver tests using Maven project

The Swings application has 3 components:

1. 'Run Tests' button : To start the execution of tests by calling a Windows batch file containing 'mvn test site' command
2. 'Stop Tests' button : I need help to implement the functionality of this button
3. Text Area: To show the console output of a batch file called through 'Run Tests' button

My scenario is that I start the execution of Selenium WebDriver tests by clicking 'Run Tests' button and its output will be displayed in the Text area attached to the application. Now, suppose in-between the execution of tests I want to click on 'Stop Tests' button and tests execution should stop, just like 'Terminate' button works on Eclipse.

**Here is the code I am using**

```
startExecutionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  

                        try {

                        //startExecutionButton.setEnabled(false);
                        startExecutionButton.setText("Tests Running...");
                        startExecutionButton.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                        String applicationURL = applicationUrlTextField.getText().trim();
                        String username = usernameTextField.getText().trim();
                        String password = passwordTextField.getText().trim();
                        String spreadsheetPath = spradsheetLocationTextField.getText().trim();
                        String testsType= testsTypeComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        String country = countryComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        // Create and overwrite properties file
                        List<String> lines = (List) Arrays.asList("applicationURL="+applicationURL, "username="+username,"password="+password,"sheetName="+testsType+"-"+country,"searchString=GHS_CLASS_"+country,"maxWaitTimeToPOLLElement=5","maxWaitTimeToFindElement=40","host=localhost","browserName=firefox","Time_Limit_To_Generate_Chemical=15");
                        Path configPath = Paths.get(getFileLocation("config.properties"));
                        try {
                            if(!configPath.toString().equals("")){
                                Files.deleteIfExists(configPath);
                            }       
                            Files.write(configPath, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Overwrite the spreadsheet
                        Path spreadsheet = Paths.get(getFileLocation("GenerateChemicalTest.xlsx"));
                        try {
                            if(!spreadsheet.toString().equals("")){
                            Files.deleteIfExists(spreadsheet);
                            }
                            Files.copy(new File(spreadsheetPath).toPath(), spreadsheet);                

                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        printLog();
                } catch (HeadlessException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


        }

       });


        private void printLog() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Open command prompt and start tests execution
        //  Process p;
            try {   
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                   Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\mavenTest.bat");

                     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

                     String line=null;
                     //System.out.println(probuilder.environment().toString());
                  while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                  }
                  input.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

[Click here for 'Swings application UI'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aY2q.png)

**mavenTest.bat code**

```
cd C:\Hazox\AutoTestHazox
C:
mvn test site
```

Comment: well without code its not so easy to help.

Comment: Show us some code also to know the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20603012/230513).

Comment: Added more details in question