# Joining JProgressBar and JTextArea (batch running console) in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder, jprogressbar

Hello I am facing few problem in combining *JtextArea* with *JProgressBar* . *JtextArea* is showing the console of batch running script. here is my code:-

```
private void initialize() {
        frmPdfPublisher = new JFrame();
        frmPdfPublisher.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\imageedit_1_6449501097.png").getImage());
        frmPdfPublisher.setTitle("PDF Publisher");
        frmPdfPublisher.setBounds(100, 100, 483, 540);
        frmPdfPublisher.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmPdfPublisher.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(10, 280, 447, 146);
        frmPdfPublisher.getContentPane().add(textArea);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        
        
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 280, 447, 146);
        frmPdfPublisher.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        
        
        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setBounds(10, 254, 447, 14);
        frmPdfPublisher.getContentPane().add(progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisible(true);
        
    
        
        JButton btnTransform = new JButton("Transform");
        btnTransform.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                String cmds[] = {"C:\\Users/Admin/Desktop/test1.bat"};
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process process = runtime.exec(cmds);
                process.getOutputStream().close();
                java.io.InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream() ;
                InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedrReader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
                String strLine = "";
                while ((strLine = bufferedrReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(strLine);
                    String newline = "\n";
                    textArea.append(strLine+newline);
                    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
                    progressBar.setString(strLine);
                    
                    
                
            }
            } catch (IOException IoException) {
                IoException.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
                
        });
```

I want to show the running script in JprogressBar as well.
*I am using Eclipse Neon.2*

**EDIT**:-

I had added few steps , but it is not showing perfect loading and is getting completed as soon the console is stopped.

Here is the edited code:-

```
JButton btnTransform = new JButton("Transform");
        btnTransform.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                try {
                String cmds[] = {"C:\\Users/Admin/Desktop/test1.bat"};
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process process = runtime.exec(cmds);
                process.getOutputStream().close();
                java.io.InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream() ;
                InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedrReader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
                String strLine = "";
                int n=progressBar.getValue();
                if(n<100){
                    n++;
                    progressBar.setValue(100);
                }
                else{
                    timer.cancel();
                }
                while ((strLine = bufferedrReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(strLine);
                    String newline = "\n";
                    textArea.append(strLine+newline);
                    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
                    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
                    progressBar.dispatchEvent(e);   
                    progressBar.getValue();
                    progressBar.updateUI();

            }
            } catch (IOException IoException) {
                IoException.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
```

*Kindly rectify me , what am I missing?*

Comment: remember to accept an answer when you have what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your `exec()` call is blocking the event dispatch thread. You'll need to run the commands in the [background](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20600721/261156). If you want to see the the progress of each line in the batch file as it runs, you'll need to read the batch file line-by-line, execute each line separately and `publish()` the result like they show [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html). If you call `setProgress()` after each line in the background, a listening progress bar to get updated, like they show [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/bound.html).

> I want my progress bar to work according to the batch file run time execution process and `n` completion 100%.

You'll need to read *all* the lines to know how many there are. Then you can set the progress like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/261156):

```
setProgress(i * (100 / n));
```

where `i` is the current line number being executed and `n` is the total number of lines. For example, if there's ten lines, the progress bar will grow by one tenth after each call.

Comment: I am able to show the console in my textarea and now I just want to read that console in running time and show it in the progressbar simultaneously.

Comment: I don't think a timer will work for this; each step in the batch file can take a different amount of time.

Comment: It is working on angular, hta  javascript , but I don't have idea in java to read batch

Comment: Your `readLine()` looks to be working; you just need to execute one line at a time in the background.

Comment: Yes , my readLine() is working fine , I don't have idea about the background read line process in java. i have a bit but I get stuck in timer section .

Comment: i wouldn't use a timer at all; if you need to slow it down, it's safe to sleep in the background.

Comment: It is not about to slow it down. I want my progress bar to work according to the batch file run time execution process and n completion 100%

Comment: I think I understand; I added more to my answer.